# Elasticsearch update index template

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-indices, elasticsearch-template

I have a question about elasticsearch index template, there is a scene of my question.

Create a template for a series indices, named `templateA`, and there are some indices create from this template, named `Index-yyyy.mm.dd2` and `Index-yyyy.mm.dd2`. After a period of time, I need create some new fields in indice, and I update the `templateA`.

SO, How to make the previously created indices use the new template? please give me some suggestion. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The template is only used at index creation. You'll have to modify your mapping or recreate your index and [reindex](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html) your data.

You can use the [PUT mapping API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.2/indices-put-mapping.html) to modify your mapping.

Comment: This answer is not very match my problem, but I didn't find a better answer! Thanks for the same.

Comment: Just to clarify - even the template used to create the index can be updated, but you need to use the PUT mapping API (which is index related) **instead of** PUT index template API.

Answer (score 0):

At least in ElasticSearch 7.15 you could [create or **update** an index template](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-template.html) using the same endpoint, also:

> Index templates are applied during data stream or index creation

It is ovious but "old" data needs to be updated in some way.

In case you are using Logstash, just restart it to do the reindex.